Accessing WireGuard VPN via UDP2RAW over SSH Tunnel
I have a Raspberry Pi 5 running a WireGuard VPN server that I use to access my home network when I'm abroad. Everything works flawlessly. Unfortunately, I can't access WireGuard from within my school's network, likely due to their restrictions on UDP traffic.
Plan
To bypass this, I found that udp2raw should help by encapsulating UDP in TCP packets. However, there's one catch: I don't want to open another port on my router specifically for the udp2raw connection.
I thought I could tunnel the udp2raw traffic over SSH to my Raspberry Pi. The idea is to avoid exposing any additional ports on my router by routing everything through an SSH tunnel. Here's what the setup looks like:
WireGuard Client -> udp2raw Client -> SSH Client ---> SSH Server -> udp2raw Server -> WireGuard Server
Problem
I attempted this setup, but unfortunately, it didn't work as expected. Testing udp2raw directly on my local network was successful, so in principle, it should work. Note that the client is a Windows laptop. Below are the configurations I've used.
What I want to know is if this setup should work in general and, if so, what I might have done wrong. Thank you in advance for your assistance!
Configurations
WireGuard Server Configuration (wg0.conf)
[Interface]
Address = 10.8.0.1/24
PreUp = udp2raw --conf-file /home/user/vpn/udp2raw-wg0.conf >/var/log/udp2raw.log 2>&1 &
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = killall udp2raw || true
MTU = 1300
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = *redacted

# Peer 1: Laptop
[Peer]
PublicKey = *redacted
AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.2/32

WireGuard Client Configuration (Windows Laptop)
[Interface]
PrivateKey = *redacted
Address = 10.8.0.2/32
DNS = 1.1.1.1
MTU = 1300

[Peer]
PublicKey = *redacted
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0 except rpi.public.ip
Endpoint = 127.0.0.1:51810

udp2raw Server Configuration
udp2raw -s -l 127.0.0.1:24820 -r 127.0.0.1:51820 -k "*redacted" -a

udp2raw Client Configuration
udp2raw -c -l 127.0.0.1:51810 -r 127.0.0.1:24820 -k "*redacted"

SSH Tunnel Setup (on client)
ssh -L 24820:localhost:24820 user@rpi.public.ip -N


SSH tunnels don't transmit raw TCP packets – they proxy the connection, by having the SSH client accept it and the SSH server establish a new one. (That is, there are really two TCP connections with data being copied from one to another.)
But according to the udp2raw docs, it doesn't create an actual TCP connection, merely generates packets that look like TCP but don't follow all of the rules. It doesn't seem like it would be able to talk to a real TCP stack and establish an actual connection to port 24820 where the SSH client is listening.
I would suggest a different approach without WireGuard, such as some kind of PPP-over-SSH (as PPP is already made to be used through stream connections) or the OpenSSH-specific IP tunnel feature (ssh -w).
You might also have luck running a more generic VPN that would be found in schools and universities, like OpenConnect (ocserv) which mimics Cisco AnyConnect – and runs over HTTPS – or perhaps IKEv2 (IPsec) which is common as Windows has a built-in client for it.
